# Xamarin Firebase Authentication for an application

Tags: firebase, xamarin

In my learning process, I created a simple (Android) game where the user's results are stored in the Firebase database. For developing purposes, I set Firebase rules to read/write without restrictions. Now I want to use rule, where only my application can read/write in the database.
How can I do it? After some browsing, I found samples where users have their own username/passwords. I don't have that kind of application. I just want that only my app has access to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a rule that gives each authenticated user a personal node at `/users/$user_id` where `$user_id` is the ID of the user obtained through [Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth). This is a common scenario for any apps that have data private to a user.

```
// These rules grant access to a node matching the authenticated
// user's ID from the Firebase auth token
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

More info can refer to here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart#user

Comment: Thank you. But I'm not sure if I understand (or maybe it wasn't clear enough, because my English is far from perfect). I have an app where users don't need to register - it isn't even foreseen. I get their name (device, date, results ...) and write them to Firebase. Every sample I can found works with user authentication. But I don't want to push users to authenicate. I want only my app is authenticated to read/write to Firebase. Or maybe I don't understand your answer?

Comment: @JanezKranjski Okey , do you have a check with the last shared doc from firebase ? The shared configuration means only your app users can access the database . And the public configration will not .https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart#public

Comment: @JanezKranjski Okey , If solved that or other problems , feel free to update here .